# Folders full of data disappeared, however shown in data recovery tools

Tags: windows, data-recovery, windows-server-2012, hidden-file

We had a incident occur on one of our servers I cannot explain.

Corporate told us to install Apex 1 AV and Carbon black onto our servers and laptops, which we did. Within 1 hour of doing this, one of our file servers is now missing 3 folders. Not just a file, or a single folder but the entire folders with 15+ years of data simply disappeared. Our corporate office cannot explain this, nor can the highly paid consultants. Despite this, I'm left looking to recover from backups, but before I did I threw on 'R-Studio' data recovery tool and the folders with data are all present and 100% healthy.

Is there some super secret folder hiding / unhiding possible here? I can't obtain access to the folders via windows / CMD , only via R-Studio.

Or shall I just pay the license price and recover the files we've lost between the backups and today via R-Studio?

Additional:
The drive on the server is a NAS device connected via iSCSI
Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: I assume there isn’t a backup?

Comment: Have you unhidden files and folders in folder options?

Comment: @Ramhound there is, I just want to see if there is an easy option before dragging that down from remote servers.

Comment: @Moab yes, it's not hidden. I've also tried to force attrib in CMD without success

Comment: I would buy the license for Rstudio, you may need it in the future also.

Comment: Did you have to reboot after the installation? In which case the issue might have been there already and just got triggered  (and not caused by the Apax installation).

Comment: Its possible the AV had false positives thought all the files contained viruses and deleted them.